# Plotting errors bars with "plot" without using axis environment from pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, plot, error-bars

In the `axis` environment of the `pgfplots` package there is a simple way to add error bars:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{filecontents}{plot2.data}
#x  y   yError
0   0.5 0.3
1   0.5 0.1
2   0.5 -0.3
3   0.5 -0.6
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot+[error bars/.cd,y dir=plus,y explicit,error bar style={color=red}]
        table [x index=0,y index=1,y error index=2] {plot2.data};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Error bars with pgfplots]

In some situations however (e.g. when you want to draw some points or lines on top of an existing image), the tikz-native `plot` function is more convenient than `axis`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{filecontents,tikz}

\begin{filecontents}{plot1.data}
#x  y
0   0.5
1   0.5
2   0.5
3   0.5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (4,0) node[anchor=west] {$x$};
    \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1) node[anchor=south] {$f(x)$};
    \draw plot[mark=*, mark options={fill=white}] file {plot1.data};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: How to add error bars to this?]

Is there a way to add similar error bars within `plot`?

Comment: I don't know if there is an alternative, at least `datavisualization` does not seem to provide error bars, but I may be wrong. However, I also do not understand what precisely is meant by "In some situations however (e.g. when you want to draw some points or lines on top of an existing image), the tikz-native `plot` function is more convenient than `axis`". How's that? I don't see a problem in putting an axis on top of some other stuff. Notice that the axis environment accepts keys like `shift` and you can turn off or control the axis scaling.

Comment: @marmot In `plot` each data point is drawn at those coordinates: the first line in `plot1.data` is a point at exactly (0,0.5). In `axis` this is not straightforward: (0,0) is the bottom-left corner of the plot, and the spacing between the datapoints is not simply the spacing between the data. So if you only want to put a list of points at specific coordinates (as when plotting on top of an existing image), `plot` is easy and straightforward. Of course it could be done with `axis` by removing the axes, shifting it, and changing the scale, but it would be a bit hacky and inconvenient